# Write a url path parameter to a query string with haProxy

Tags: regex, query-string, haproxy

I'm trying to re-write a URL such as

```
http://ourdomain.com/hotels/vegas?cf=0
```

to

```
http://ourdomain.com?d=vegas&cf=0
```

using haProxy.

We used to do it with Apache using

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?\??(.*)$ ?d=$1&$2 [QSA]
```

I've tried

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /hotels/(.*)     \1\ /?d=\2
```

But that gives me `http://ourdomain.com?d=vegas?cf=0`

And

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /hotels/([^/]+)/?\??(.*)     \1\ /?d=\2&\3
```

Just gives me a 400 error.

It would be nice to do it with acl's but I can't see how that would work.

Answer (score 4):

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /hotels/([^/]+)/?\??(.*)     \1\ /?d=\2&\3
```

> Just gives me a 400 error.

`([^/]+)` is too greedy when everything following it `/?\??(.*)` is optional.  It's mangling the last part of the request, leading to the 400.

Remember what sort of data you're working with:

```
GET /path?query HTTP/1.(0|1)
```

Replace `([^/]+)` with `([^/\ ]+)` so that anything after and including the space will be captured by `\3`, not `\2`.

---

Update: it seems that the above is not quite perfect, since the alignment of the `?` still doesn't work out.  This -- and the original 400 error -- highlight some of the pitfalls with `req[i]rep` -- it's very low level request munging.

HAProxy 1.6 introduced several new capabilities that make request tweaking much cleaner, and this is actually a good case to illustrate several of them together.  Note that these examples also use anonymous ACLs, wrapped in `{` `}`.  The documentation seems to discourage these a little bit -- but this is only because they're unwieldy to maintain when you need to test the same set of conditions for multiple reasons (named ACLs can of course be more easily reused), but they're perfect for a case like this.  Note that the braces must be surrounded by at least 1 whitespace character due to configuration parser limitations.

**Variables**, scoped to request (go out of scope as soon as a back-end is selected), response (go into scope only after the back-end responds), transaction (persistent from request to response, these can be used before the trip to the back-end and are still in scope when the response comes back), or session (in scope across multiple requests by this browser during this connection, if the browser reuses the connection), can be used to stash values.

**The `regsub()` converter** takes the preceding value as its input and returns that value passed through a simple regex replacement.

If the path starts with `/hotels/`, capture the path, scrub out `^/hotels/` (replacing it with the empty string that appears after the next comma), and stash it in a request variable called `req.hotel`.

```
http-request set-var(req.hotel) path,regsub(^/hotels/,) if { path_beg /hotels/ }
```

Processing of most `http-request` steps is done in configuration file order, so, at the next instruction, if (and only if) that variable has a value, we use **`http-request set-path`** with an argument of `/` in order to empty the path.  Testing the variable is needed so that we don't do this with every request -- only the ones for /hotels/.  It might be that you actually need something more like `if { path_reg /hotels/.+ }` since `/hotels/` by itself might be a valid path we should leave alone.

```
http-request set-path / if { var(req.hotel) -m found }
```

Then, we use **`http-request set-query`** to set the query string to a value created by concatenating the value of the `req.hotel` variable with `&` and the original query string, which we obtain with using the **`query` fetch**.

```
http-request set-query d=%[var(req.hotel)]&%[query] if { var(req.hotel) -m found }
```

Note that the `query` fetch and `http-request set-query` both have some magical behavior -- they take care of the `?` for you.  The `query` fetch does not return it, and `http-request set-query` does not expect you to provide it.  This is helpful because we may need to be able to handle requests correctly whether or not the `?` is present in the original request, without having to manage it ourselves.

With the above configuration, `GET /hotels/vegas?&cf=0 HTTP/1.1` becomes `GET /?d=vegas&cf=0 HTTP/1.1`.

If the initial query string is completely empty, `GET /hotels/vegas HTTP/1.1` becomes `GET /?d=vegas& HTTP/1.1`.  That looks a little strange, but it should be completely valid.  A slightly more convoluted configuration to test for the presence of an intial query string could prevent that, but I don't see it being an issue.

So, we've turned 1 line of configuration into 3, but I would argue that those three lines are much more intuitive about what they are accomplishing and it's certainly a less delicate operation than massaging the entire start line of the request with a regex.  Here they are, together, with some optional whitespace:

```
http-request set-var(req.hotel) path,regsub(^/hotels/,) if { path_beg /hotels/ }
http-request set-path /                                 if { var(req.hotel) -m found }
http-request set-query d=%[var(req.hotel)]&%[query]     if { var(req.hotel) -m found }
```

Comment: Thanks. That gives me `d=vegas?cf=0&` (read from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in php).

Comment: Ah, so it does.  Apologies, I found one problem and overlooked a second one.  That's what I get for parsing regexes with my eyeballs.  Incidentally, is this HAProxy >= 1.6?  There are some cleaner methods for manipulations like this, if so.

Comment: Yes we're on HAProxy 1.6 :) - Cleaner methods sounds great. I've managed to get something working. I'll post my regex solution, but would swap it for a cleaner method any day! (and I'm sure a cleaner solution would useful for anyone coming back here). +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @AidanEwen see what you think of the 1.6+ alternative, above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution using `reqrep`

```
acl is_destination path_beg /hotels/
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /hotels/([^/\ \?]+)/?\??([^\ ]*)(.*)$     \1\ /?d=\2&\3\4 if is_destination
```

I'm hoping that the acl will remove the need to run regex on everything (hence lightening the load a bit), but I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: Thanks to @Michael - sqlbot for getting me 99% of the way there.